# "I didn't realize"

Tags: tenses, past-tense

Is the phrase "I didn't realize" always followed by a clause in the Simple Past tense, or it can be followed with other tenses as well?
For context: "I didn't realize there were times you inadvertently dramatized things" vs "I didn't realize there are times you inadvertently dramatize things"

Comment: I look forward to the real answer. But also consider "I hadn't realized". I think the following clause could certainly use other tenses.

Comment: Consider the following: "When we started this class, I didn't realize you would be such a difficult lab partner."

Answer (score 1):

In your example, both are grammatical and natural, and they mean the same thing.

Comment: Have you a reference to back up this assertion? Answers without supporting references come across as (and sometimes are) mere opinion, and are sometimes wrong.